# CSS Changes on clicking previous in a multi step form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing an **eCommerce website** using **Django** and is depoloyed on [sby.delhinerds.com](http://sby.delhinerds.com). On this page: http://sby.delhinerds.com/products/shirts-1/, I require a multi-step form where the user could choose his/her customization and proceed with further customization.

Although, The image selection and the next button are working fine but when I click on **"Previous button"**, the **CSS** or **Javascript** alters and the design breaks. I have been trying to get it work properly but no luck. Please help.

Thanks.

Steps on How to reproduce the error: 
1. Go to http://sby.delhinerds.com/products/shirts-1/ 
2. Click on any image and make it selected
3. Click on next
4. On the next step, click on previous, the CSS or JS drastically changes.

My HTML, CSS and Javascript/jQuery is

```js
   
  $('.images_list li').click(function() {
   $('.images_list .selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
   $("#"+clicked).removeClass("hidden").siblings().addClass("hidden");
  });
    
 
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 500,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 0,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
});
```

```css
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;*/
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;

 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}

.images_list li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
   }

  .images_list li span {
    display:none;
   position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:30px;
   width:24px;
   height:24px;
  }
  .border {
   border: 0;
   background: url(upload/check.jpg);
  }
  .selected {
   border: 3px solid pink;
    position:relative;
   width:200px;
  }
  .hidden {
      display:none;
  }
  .images_list li.selected span {
      display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:500px;">

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar" style="width:1000px;">
<li class="active">Fabric</li>
<li>Collars</li>
<li>Cuffs</li>
<li>Back</li>
<li>Front</li>
</ul>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset style="width:1000px;">
<div class="images_list">
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width:1000px;">
<div class="images_list">
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width:1000px;">
<div class="images_list">
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width:1000px;">
<div class="images_list">
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset style="width:1000px;">
<div class="images_list">
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_1">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/1.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
<li class="border" title="content_2">
<img class="selectables" src="{% static "images/collar/2.png" %}"  />
<span>
<img src="{% static "images/select_itm.png" %}" />
</span>
</li>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
</form>

</div>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="color_size top_border_with_pad">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
<div class="product_color">
<span>color</span>
<div class="sorting margin-left-15">
<label>
<select>
<option selected>- Select color - </option>
<option>Yellow</option>
<option>Black</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<span>measurements</span>
<div class="sorting margin-left-15">
<label>
<select>
<option selected>- Select color - </option>
<option>Yellow</option>
<option>Black</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding-right">
<div class="product_size floatright">
<span>Size</span>
<div class="sorting margin-left-15">
<label>
<select>
<option selected>- Select dize - </option>
<option>40</option>
<option>50</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<span>Appoinment date</span>
<div class="sorting margin-left-15">
<label>
<select>
<option selected>- Select dize - </option>
<option>40</option>
<option>50</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply previous Function for this property `position:relative`

```
previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'position':'relative','opacity': opacity});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, Thanks a lot. I was having issues auto scale height of fieldsets on clicking "Previous" button, your solution fixed !

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery add `'position':'relative'` at `previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});`

Resulting will be

`previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')','position':'relative', 'opacity': opacity});`